# Reescritura de url con mod_rewrite y .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo una URL en mi web: `https://www.miweb.com/componente/nombre/contratar`

Me gustaría que no se mostrase "nombre" ya que la empresa ha cambiado, pero que la URL siga llevando al mismo lugar, ya que sino la contratación no funciona.

¿Es posible mostrar al usuario una URL pero que se esté apuntando hacia la verdadera?

Lo he hecho de esta manera en el archivo .htaccess con mod_rewrite, pero solo me redirige y claro, sale error 404.

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^componente/nombre/contratar$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/componente/contratar$1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que hiciste está perfecto como primer paso. Solamente hay que agregarle otra regla. Lo que estás buscando es una **reescritura**: que Apache modificque la URL pero que nada de esto vaya al usuario como redirección.

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /

# Tu regla para redireccionar (con algunos detalles modificados)
RewriteRule ^componente/nombre/contratar(/.*|$) componente/contratar$1 [NC,R=302,L]

# Reescribir de  /componente/contratar/*  a  /componente/nombre/contratar/*
RewriteRule ^componente/contratar(/.*|$) componente/nombre/contratar$1 [NC,END]
```

- La clave en esta última redirección es utilizar [[END]](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) para que no siga intentando aplicar otras reglas y no caiga en un loop infinito entre redirección y reescritura.
- Subí una demo a un hosting gratuito que se puede probar en http://mariano.uphero.com/145740/componente/nombre/contratar

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me aparece este error: "The requested URL /componente/nombre/contratar was not found on this server." La url en la barra de direcciones https://www.miweb.com/componente/nombre aparece correctamente pero luego aparece un 404. Quizás me falte algo o esté haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Si existe /componente/nombre/contratar, puede ser xq le falta algo a la dirección? la url completa es https://www.miweb.com/componente/nombre/contratar

Comment: @Norak claaaro, error mío. Me confundí `contratar` con `nombre` en la última regla, perdón me hice un lío con los nombres de las carpetas... Ya lo [modifiqué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/145753/revisions) y debería funcionarte... La útlima no era desde `componente/nombre` sino desde `componente/contratar`

Comment: Tienes razón, ese era uno de los problemas. Pero he vuelto a probar y me pasa lo mismo. Salta el mismo error, no falta nada del tipo: http://%{HTTP_HOST}? es como que le faltase algo a la url base cuando se hace la 2ª RewriteRule

Comment: @Norak no es necesario el host para una regla, para nada, Apache usa el host actual. Podés ver un ejemplo que subí a un hosting funcionando. Estoy pensando que otra configuración podría entrar en conflicto, pero no se me ocurre... ¿Es el único .htaccess en todas estas carpetas, y son las únicas 2 reglas? Si hay más reglas, probaría desactivarlas para ir depurando de a pasos.

Comment: Gracias @Mariano, voy a probar lo que dices. Me estás ayudando mucho y he aprendido mucho con tu ayuda. Ya te comento a ver qué consigo

Comment: Sigo sin conseguirlo, creo que ya a partir de aquí es problema mío con alguna ruta... Podrías pasarme los archivos de ejemplo que subiste al hosting para ver las estructura? a ver si así me ayuda a encontrar mi fallo... Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Norak lamento que no encontraras el error, realmente no hay nada que pueda hacer sin ver el log de Apache o más información de tu caso específico... En cuanto a lo que subí, el código del ..htaccess que está usando aparece en la misma página (que es realmente lo mismo que esta respuesta con la excepción de que le cambié el `RewriteBase` porque es una subcarpeta) sólo están `index.php` en cada carpeta y el `/145740/.htaccess`

Comment: Vale, gracias @Mariano, la verdad que tu solución es perfecta! funciona bien, sólo que será un problema mío de rutas. De verdad, mil gracias por toda tu ayuda :)